# regex for character appearing at most once

Tags: python, regex

I want to check a string that contains the period, ".", at most once in python.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what would be valid strings, and what would be invalid strings?  The question is a little vague.  For example, can there be characters between the periods?  Are you only talking about consecutive characters, or all characters in the string?

Comment: I want to check for integers and decimal.  So valid strings in this case would be 2.34 or 2. Invalid strings would be 2.2.3.  Actually, what i have at the moment is this: [if not re.search("[0-9\.]+$", item) or not re.search("^*\.?*$", item): return "invalid value"].  If you know a better way, please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[^.]*\.?[^.]*$
```

And be sure to `match`, don't `search`

```
>>> dot = re.compile("[^.]*\.[^.]*$")
>>> dot.match("fooooooooooooo.bar")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7651838>
>>> dot.match("fooooooooooooo.bar.sad") is None
True
>>>
```

**Edit**:

If you consider only integers and decimals, it's even easier:

```
def valid(s):
    return re.match('[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?$', s) is not None

assert valid("42")
assert valid("13.37")
assert valid("1.")
assert not valid("1.2.3.4")
assert not valid("abcd")
```

Comment: Should you have a `^` at the start of the expression, or is that implied because you're matching?

Comment: [Explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), so there should be a `^` at the start of the expression.

Answer (score 5):

No regexp is needed, see [`str.count()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

> `str.count(sub[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

```
>>> "A.B.C.D".count(".")
3
>>> "A/B.C/D".count(".")
1
>>> "A/B.C/D".count(".") == 1
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
re.search('^[^.]*\.?[^.]*$', 'this.is') != None

>>> re.search('^[^.]*\.?[^.]*$', 'thisis') != None
True
>>> re.search('^[^.]*\.?[^.]*$', 'this.is') != None
True
>>> re.search('^[^.]*\.?[^.]*$', 'this..is') != None
False
```

(Matches period zero or one times.)

Answer (score 0):

While period is special char it must be escaped. So "\.+" should work.

EDIT:

Use '?' instead of '+' to match one or zero repetitions.
Have a look at: [re — Regular expression operations](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Comment: That will match the period 1 or more times.  I think the question wants 0 or 1 times.

Comment: You are right. In regexp plus means one or more. I should use question mark instead of plus.

Answer (score 0):

If the period should exist only once in the entire string, then use the `?` operator:

```
^[^.]*\.?[^.]*$
```

Breaking this down:

1. `^` matches the beginning of the string
2. `[^.]` matches zero or more characters that are not periods
3. `\.?` matches the period character (must be escaped with `\` as it's a reserved char) exactly 0 or 1 times
4. `[^.]*` is the same pattern used in 2 above
5. `$` matches the end of the string

As an aside, personally I wouldn't use a regular expression for this (unless I was checking other aspects of the string for validity too).  I would just use the count function.

Comment: Unless you ensure you match the *whole* string, this will match ".." (regex matches first period, and then finishes successfully without considering the second period).

Comment: This will not cover the case when a string contains two periods with other letters between them.

Comment: @davidi - agreed, I've updated the answer and breakdown of the expression

Comment: Why don't we have to escape the periods after the inversion: `[^.]*`, but we have to escape it otherwise: `\.?`?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to check? If you have a number in a string, I now guess you will want to handle it as a number soon. Perhaps you can do this without *Looking Before You Leap*:

```
try:
  value = float(input_str)
except ValueError:
  ...
else:
  ...
```